# Problema ao persistir objeto com @ManyToOne - JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistência

Estou com o seguinte problema: Consigo salvar/persistir os dois objetos abaixo, porém o JPA não está vinculando o ID da `DeclaracaoImportacao` na coluna ID classe/entidade .

Segue código

```java
@Entity
@Table (name = "declaracaoimportacao")
public class DeclaracaoImportacao implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String importadorNome;
    private double freteTotalMoeda;
    private String importadorEnderecoMunicipio;
    private String importadorEnderecoLogradouro;
    private int importadorEnderecoCep;
    private String importadorEnderecoBairro;
    private int importadorEnderecoNumero;
    private String importadorEnderecoUf;
    private String conhecimentoCargaEmbarqueData;
    private String dataRegistro;
    private int freteMoedaNegociadaCodigo;  
    private int numeroDI;
    private double freteValorMoedaNegociada;
    private double freteCollect;
    private double fretePrepaid;
    private double freteTotalReais;


    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy = "declaracaoImportacao")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private List<Adicao> adicao  = new ArrayList<Adicao>();

    public DeclaracaoImportacao(){

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Adicao> getAdicoes() {
        return adicao;
    }

    public void setAdicao(ArrayList<Adicao> adicao) {
        this.adicao = adicao;
    }

    public void addAdicao(Adicao adicao) {
        addAdicao(adicao, true);
    }

    void addAdicao(Adicao adicao, boolean set) {
        if (adicao != null) {
            if(getAdicoes().contains(adicao)) {
                getAdicoes().set(getAdicoes().indexOf(adicao), adicao);
            }
            else {
                getAdicoes().add(adicao);
            }
            if (set) {
                adicao.setDi(this, false);              
            }
        }
    }
  // outros getters e setters

  @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == this)
            return true;
        if ((object == null) || !(object instanceof DeclaracaoImportacao))
            return false;

        final DeclaracaoImportacao di = (DeclaracaoImportacao)object;

        if (id != null && di.getId() != null) {
            return id.equals(di.getId());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

A seguir a classe `Adicao`, que deveria receber o ID que vem da classe `DeclaracaoImportacao`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "adicao")
public class Adicao implements Serializable {   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_adicao;

    @Column
    private String condicaoVendaIncoterm;
    private int paisOrigemMercadoriaCodigo;
    private String paisOrigemMercadoriaNome;    

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="id")
    private DeclaracaoImportacao declaracaoImportacao;  

    public Adicao(){

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id_adicao;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id_adicao = id;
    }
    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    public DeclaracaoImportacao getDi() {
        return declaracaoImportacao;
    }
    public void setDi(DeclaracaoImportacao di) {
        setDi(di, true);
    }

    void setDi(DeclaracaoImportacao di, boolean add) {
        this.declaracaoImportacao = di;
        if (di != null && add) {
            di.addAdicao(this, false);
        }
    }
  // outros getters and setter

  @Override
     public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == this)
            return true;
        if ((object == null) || !(object instanceof Adicao))
            return false;

        final Adicao adicao = (Adicao)object;

        if (id_adicao != null && adicao.getId() != null) {
            return id_adicao.equals(adicao.getId());
        }
        return false;
    }   

}
```

Como podem ver me preocupei bastante em manter a integridade dos objetos no banco de dados.

Segue as classe DAO para `DeclaracaoImportacao`:

```java
public class DeclaracaoImportacaoFacade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    DeclaracaoImportacaoDAO diDAO = new DeclaracaoImportacaoDAO();

    public void createDeclaracaoImportacao(DeclaracaoImportacao di){
        diDAO.beginTransaction();
      // Esse método save está dentro de uma superclasse DAO que faz a criação do EntityManager
        diDAO.save(di);
        diDAO.commitAndCloseTransaction();
    }
```

E essa é a classe Pai `GenericDAO`:

```java
abstract class GenericDAO<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JSFCrudPU");
    private EntityManager em;

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public void beginTransaction() {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    public void commit() {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void rollback() {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }

    public void closeTransaction() {
        em.close();
    }

    public void commitAndCloseTransaction() {
        commit();
        closeTransaction();
    }

    public void flush() {
        em.flush();
    }

    public void joinTransaction() {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.joinTransaction();
    }

    public GenericDAO(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public void save(T entity) {
        em.persist(entity);

    }

    public void delete(Object id, Class<T> classe) {
        T entityToBeRemoved = em.getReference(classe, id);

        em.remove(entityToBeRemoved);
    }

    public T update(T entity) {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }

    public T find(int entityID) {
        return em.find(entityClass, entityID);
    }

    public T findL(Long entityID) {
        return em.find(entityClass, entityID);
    }
}
```

Quando eu vou persistir a entidade `DeclaracaoImportacao` automaticamente ele persiste a classe `Adicao`, ou seja não preciso chamar um método save(`Adicao`) para a classe adição.

Mas, o JPA como eu disse anteriomente está deixando de vincular o ID da `DeclaracaoImportacao` na tabela `Adicao` isso faz com que a relação N->1 não seja criada.

Segue prints mostrando os objetos já persistidos no MySQL.[image: DeclaracaoImportacao persistido]

`Adicao`: [image: Adicao persistida]

Realmente procurei de tudo pessoal, poderiam dar uma força ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em português! Sua pergunta está muito clara e muito bem descrita, boa elaboração!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No JPA existe o conceito de dono do relacionamento (relationship owner). No seu caso é a entidade Adicao que possui uma chave estrangeira para a entidade DeclaracaoImportacao, portanto é a entidade Adicao que é dona do relacionamento!

Se você criar uma nova adição e adicioná-la na lista de uma declaracaoImportacao, ao salvar a declaracao a adicao também será salva, pois você especificou para fazer o persist em cascata com o código abaixo:

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy = "declaracaoImportacao")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private List<Adicao> adicao  = new ArrayList<Adicao>();
```

Porém o relacionamento tem dois lados! Então você deve adicionar a adicao na lista da declaracaoImportacao e também adicionar a declaracaoImportacao na adicicao!

```
DeclaracaoImportacao declaracaoImportacao = new DeclaracaoImportacao();
Adicao adicao = new Adicao();

declaracaoImportacao.getAdicoes().add(adicao);  // Colocando a adicao na lista
adicao.setDi(declaracaoImportacao)             // Isso é importante!

diDAO.save(declaracaoImportacao);
```

Agora sim a adicao vai ser salva com o id certo!

Resumindo como a classe Adicao que é dona do relacionamento é ela que faz a diferença e não a classe DeclaracaoImportacao. Como na classe adicao o seu campo declaracaoImportacao estava null, o hibernate vai salvar null no banco de dados. Se fosse ou contrário, ou seja, a classe adicao com o campo declaracaoImportacao com a di certa e a classe declaracaoImportacao com a lista vazia o hibernate iria salvar tudo corretamente, pois a classe declaracaoImportacao não é dona do relacionamento então ela nem faz diferença! Mas mesmo assim é interessante sempre deixar as referências consistentes, então sempre adicione os dois um no outro.

Comment: Olá Sérgio, muito obrigado pela resposta altamente detalhada vou tentar implementar essas alterações aqui. Se der certo já marco como resposta !

Comment: Sérgio,estou com outro problema, as vezes vou ter mais de uma Adicao, a dica que me passou só funciona quando tenho só uma Adicao. Estou tentando:
 `for(int i =0; declaracImport.getAdicoes().size() <= i;i++ ){
  adi = declaracImport.getAdicoes().get(i);  
  declaracImport.getAdicoes().add(adi);  
  adi.setDi(declaracImport);
  }  
diDAO.save(declaracaoImport;`

O único jeito que funcionou foi : 
`adi = declaracImport.getAdicoes().get(0);  
  declaracImport.getAdicoes().add(adi);  
  adi.setDi(declaracImport);` 
Veja que aqui só consigo vincular o id de uma Adição em uma Declaracao

Comment: Funciona com quantas adicoes você quiser. Você já tem o método addAdicao(Adicao adicao) faça com que ele já adicione um objeto no outro. Algo como: `void addAdicao(Adicao adicao){ adicao.setDi(this); this.getAdicoes().add(adicao); }` Daí sempre use esse método quando quiser adicionar uma adicao. Talvez seja interessante fazer uma cópia da adição dentro do método e adicionar a cópia pra não alterar a original.

Comment: Obrigado Sergio , o que deu certo foi : 
`DeclaracaoImportacao declaracaoImportacao = new DeclaracaoImportacao();

  Adicao adi = new Adicao();
  
  while (x < declaracaoImportacao.getAdicoes().size()){
   
   adi = declaracaoImportacao.getAdicoes().get(x);
   declaracaoImportacao.addAdicao(adi);
   x++;
  
  }
diDAO.save(declaracaoImportacao);`

Comment: Ah sim, olhando bem agora acho que não tinha entendido a sua dúvida do comentário direto. Se eu puder ajudar em mais alguma coisa é só perguntar! :)

Comment: @MatheusMaciel esse código está meio estranho, você está pegando um adição da lista e adicionando de novo na lista? Não sei se isso faz sentido. Não seria algo assim que você quer: for(int i = 0; i <= declaracImport.getAdicoes().size(); i++ ){ adi = declaracImport.getAdicoes().get(i); adi.setDi(declaracImport); } diDAO.save(declaracaoImport); ?

Comment: fiz isso, realmente estava estranho daquela forma !